# Using multi-VLC Player in the same UIView cause lag

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, vlc, rtsp

I'm developing an iOS app using swift, in this app I want monitor several IP camera in the same view.

I created two VLCMediaPlayer and feed them with two different rtsp link and both of them result in extremely lag. I've also change the "network-caching" to 10000 for both two VLC Player. If I use just one VLCMediaPlayer in that view, the streaming is fine.

I'm wondering is this the right solution for display multi-vlc player? Or I should use other solution or other media player?

Comment: Does it help to create both players without any options? What's your testing device?

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've tried create both without any options, but it still not streaming smooth. I use iphone 5 to test, even i use it in iOS simulator with wired network, still have the same problem.

Comment: There's a app call 'iWatch DVR' could watch many stream in the same time. But maybe they aren't use vlcPlayer!